# How to define a relationship between 2 tables in different microservices spring boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, microservices

I'm trying to define the relationship between 2 entity
1st: Product
2nd : Order
both of them in different services, for Order, need to define the many-to-many relationship with the Product however I don't have the reference to this table since it exists in different service, how should i define this relationship

I tried to google but I couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referencing the `Product` as a Java reference you would just have the `productId` in your `Order` or more likely in your `OrderItem`.

This is actually exactly how Spring Data JDBC models aggregates and references between aggregates which in turn is based on Domain Driven Design practices. You can read about it here: https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/24/spring-data-jdbc-references-and-aggregates